# Blank page when viewing wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, login, htaccess

I just add a new user for my website and everything went perfectly. Suddenly when I am trying to go to `www.example.com/wp-admin` it only shows a white blank page and redirects to this address: `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

How can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you ain't got debugging activated. Please [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) - [blueprint for `wp-config.php`](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) - and file an [edit] so we can look at your error messages.

Comment: Edit the wp-config.php file and add the following "define('WP_DEBUG', true);" without qotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a .htaccess file  in the root of your site (where the "wp-content" folder exists)
The default .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know where I Should do this?

Comment: Where should I add this file after creating that?

Comment: Would be great if you can add an explanation to where all of this should go for future reference for other users that might not know how to use this :-)

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: nothing changed. I made this file with this name : htaccess.htaccess and upload it to wp-content. Next to index.php of wp-content.

Comment: no you chould upload it in the same directory of "wp-content" and not inside it, and the file name is ".htaccess" and not "htaccess.htaccess", if you can't name it ".htaccess" you can upload it as "htaccess" and then rename it to ".htaccess"

Comment: I did it. nothing happened. after changing name in there the file has been gone. :D

Comment: I upload it in the mail root. in public html.

Comment: @Aminesrine Find any way to solve it?

Comment: I don't think it's due to the added user, but try to delete it from the database (you find users in "wp_users" table)

Comment: @Aminesrine Nothing changed.

Comment: try to rename all plugins or to remove them, and see if it's ok